# IPhone App Submission Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have finally gotten my first app to work properly and I'm attempting to send it to the App Store. In my Application Loader, I'm getting this error:

```
Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleResourceSpecification
```

I have read on the following SO question that this could be because I am Building on the simulator and then zipping up the app, and sending this instead of building on a proper device.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180201/cant-upload-application-binary-to-the-app-store
```

However, when I provision a distribution profile, I can't select my IPod Touch under my devices when I have App Store selected. When I switch it to AdHoc I can select it, then I can Build it on the device perfectly, everything works. Has anybody had this issue before?

Any advice would help me here, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An App Store build can't be run on a device using Xcode. It's only good for submission.

Comment: I see, well that would explain why I can't do that! Have you had any experience with this error?

Comment: What error? I thought you had the error fixed, and only found it weird that you couldn't install the App Store build on your device...

Comment: Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleResourceSpecification

Comment: In the SO question referenced in the question somebody answered with this: I assume you're uploading a .zip file.

I just checked an app I uploaded, and CFBundleResourceSpecification is only in the signed versions (i.e. the device builds).

Comment: Did you create/download an App Store provisioning profile? Are you building your app for device/distribution (not simulator/distribution)?